# How to tell boss that its often too cold with the ceiling fan running?

Tags: colleagues, temperature

We live in a tropical area where room temperature is anywhere between 25-28 degree celcius. I am used to more hotter temperatures as I am from a coastal city. My boss (the owner of the startup) always turns on the fan and it makes the part where we sit cold. Having asked him to turn it off for sometime previously I have met with negative responses. I find him intimidating with his smile but condescending language.

At times I can ignore this cold air and work but at times my hands feel too too cold to type anything. I also suffer from a condition where my skin breaks in reaction to cold temperature. It makes me itch all my body which probably is not a good visual in office space.

There is no option of work elsewhere because ours is the only floor that has monitors and related people sit next to each other so nobody is willing to trade places with me. Downstairs floor albeit quiet has no monitor and working on code on my 11" laptop is not very productive for me. I can't seem to figure out any hack to overcome this situation. I'd rather quietly fix this myself than talk to him because it seems like nobody else has this issue.

Background info: Am new to the workspace and because of colleagues poking fun at my eating and buying habits previously, I don't talk to them unless absolutely required to be cordial. Nor am I a star performer/great at my work so asking anything something small like will just make me seem more "difficult" to work with.

Perhaps somebody has an idea on how I should go about this on my own?

Comment: Can you put on a sweatshirt/ sweater/ jacket etc.?  It seems very odd that a mere ceiling fan would make a 25 C room cold enough to cause numbness in your hands.  If you have a medical condition, have you spoken with your physician about ways to mitigate the issue?

Comment: @JustinCave perhaps numb was not the word I was looking for. Have edited the question. Just that having cold hands is uncomfortable and directly sitting under the ceiling fan makes me drowsy as well.

Comment: "Hey boss, at times my hands feel too too cold to type anything. I also suffer from a condition where my skin breaks in reaction to cold temperature. It makes me itch all my body which probably is not a good visual in office space" would be a good way to tell your boss.

Comment: Your skin likely breaks because it gets dried out from the constant air movement - unless you have a specific medical condition, lotion should help with that. Dry skin frequently happens to me in air conditioned spaces. (I'm not a doctor so don't take this as medical advice.)

Comment: Are you getting a breeze that could be blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand where you are coming from as I find the air conditioning in my office is way too strong (cold) for me. I usually wear a cardigan and/or light jacket inside (even when it is really hot outside) and when I feel particularly cold I drink more tea/coffee which helps warm me from the inside. Perhaps try this if you haven't already.

Obviously the fan would not make the office cold but the movement of air on your skin feels quite cool. I suggest layering up, particularly warm footwear as the feet feel cold more, or even a light/fashionable summer scarf?

If it is a warm climate the office will probably feel stuffy without the fan, so I think you probably won't be able to get the others to agree to turning it off. I think your easiest solution will be to adjust your outfit. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Wearing a jacket is the best possible solution to me.
I have seen many of my colleagues doing so.

> I am used to more hotter temperatures as I am from a coastal city.

You are used with more hotter temperatures, this is your personal matter(why would others worry for this).

> my skin breaks in reaction to cold temperature

Use a moisturizer.

---

Another idea is ask for change of seat whenever a vacant space is available.

As you are new at this place it may take some time for you to adapt. It will be alright in 1 or 2 months.